# Impala group by on partitioned columns

Tags: group-by, partitioning, impala

I have an impala internal table partitioned on some columns, and I want to perform a group by on some fields including the partitioning columns, basically my query looks like this:

```
select market, col1, count(1) from mytable group by market, col1
```

with 'market' being the partitioning column.

Then I got 'Memory limit exceeded', but if I issue a query like this:

```
select market, col1, count(1) from mytable where market='US' group by market, col1
```

Then I get my result without memory issues.

So it seems to me that in impala, partition pruning does happen when partitioning columns are in 'where' clauses, but doesn't work when they are in 'group by' am I right? If my assumption is right then it shocks me since group by on a partitioning column is just running group by for a hdfs subdirectory.

Here is the beginning of the impala profile message when I run my first query:

```
Estimated Per-Host Requirements: Memory=7.59TB VCores=2

F02:PLAN FRAGMENT [UNPARTITIONED]   04:EXCHANGE [UNPARTITIONED]
     hosts=39 per-host-mem=unavailable
     tuple-ids=1 row-size=133B cardinality=28530506252

F01:PLAN FRAGMENT [HASH(market,col1)] DATASTREAM SINK [FRAGMENT=F02, EXCHANGE=04, UNPARTITIONED]   03:AGGREGATE [FINALIZE]   |  output: count:merge(1)   |  group by: market, col1   |  hosts=39 per-host-mem=3.80TB   |  tuple-ids=1 row-size=133B cardinality=28530506252   |   02:EXCHANGE [HASH(market,col1)]
     hosts=39 per-host-mem=0B
     tuple-ids=1 row-size=133B cardinality=28530506252

F00:PLAN FRAGMENT [RANDOM]   DATASTREAM SINK [FRAGMENT=F01, EXCHANGE=02, HASH(market,col1)] 01:AGGREGATE   |  output: count(1)   |  group by: market, col1   |  hosts=39 per-host-mem=3.80TB   |  tuple-ids=1 row-size=133B cardinality=28530506252   |   00:SCAN HDFS [mytable, RANDOM]
 partitions=5057/5057 files=5397 size=207.71GB
 table stats: 28530506252 rows total
 column stats: all
 hosts=39 per-host-mem=384.00MB
 tuple-ids=0 row-size=125B cardinality=28530506252
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not happen because by using a `WHERE` clause in fact you limit the number of groups Impala have to perform operations on.

In the Cloudera official documentation you can find that:

> GROUP BY on a unique or high cardinality column.Impala allocates some
>   handler structures for each different value in a GROUP BY query.
>   Having millions of different GROUP BY values could exceed the memory
>   limit.

In fact the piece of documentation is into the section "What are the most memory-intensive operations?".

At this point I think that you can talk with the administrators and ask to improve memory on a node(s) (but honestly I have no idea how to check what node(s) are out of memory for that operation) or you can try to write a smarter query, maybe by using an external table, or a view.